# Сигналы и слоты, QMenu

Tags: c++, qt

Никак не могу законнектить слот `list(QString)` с сигналом `triggred() QAction *ToUpper`.

Класс `MainWindow`:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <touppercase.h>
 
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMenu *menu;
    menu = menuBar()->addMenu("&Menu");
    QMenu *User_plug_ins = new QMenu("&User_plug_ins", menu);
    menu->addMenu(User_plug_ins);
    QAction *ToUpper = new QAction("ToUpper", this);
 
    User_plug_ins->addAction(ToUpper);
 
    QString string = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    ToUpperCase *size = new ToUpperCase();
 
 
}
 
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Класс `ToUpperCase(.h и .cpp)`:

```cpp
#ifndef TOUPPERCASE_H
#define TOUPPERCASE_H
 
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>
class ToUpperCase : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ToUpperCase(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
signals:
 
public slots:
    void list(QString);
 
};
 
#endif // TOUPPERCASE_H
 
 
 
ToUpperCase::ToUpperCase(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
 
 
}
void ToUpperCase::list(QString string)
{
  string = string.toUpper();
  QMessageBox str;
  str.setText(string);
  str.exec();
}
```

пробовал так, но он почему то метод `list` не видит

```cpp
connect(ToUpper, SIGNAL(triggered()), size ,SLOT(list(string)));
```

а такой метод он выполняет:

```cpp
connect(ToUpper, &QAction::triggered, qApp, &QApplication::quit);
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Приведите код в самом вопросе, а не по ссылке

Comment: Не надо задавать такой же вопрос ещё раз, пока этот существует

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [QMenu, сигналы и слоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183767/qmenu-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b)